# Android: restart remote service and bind it again

Tags: android, service, bind, restart

I have a remote service in android. It's binded to my list activity and sends some messages to it. The service contins scheduled task in it. I also have preference: refresh interval for my service. All I want is to restart the service when user changes refresh interval. Butif I do it in onSharedPreferenceChanged() then I loose the connection from my list activity. How can I solve it? Thanks.

I know that I can use Broadcast Reciever. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a remote service in android.

Why? Why not a local service?

> The service contins scheduled task in it.

Why? Why not use `AlarmManager`, so your service isn't just sitting around in RAM, watching time pass?

> All I want is to restart the service when user changes refresh interval.

Why? Why not just change your `AlarmManager` schedule? If you use a local service, your service can use a `SharedPreferences` and `setOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` to be automatically notified of changes in the refresh interval.

Comment: I use remote service cause I want it to be active all the time. It does some usefull actions...

Comment: @Nick: First, you don't need a remote service to have one that is "active all the time". Second, the user probably does not want your service to be "active all the time". Third, the OS will prevent you from having a service that is "active all the time". Hence, I very strongly recommend that you redesign your application to avoid the everlasting service, unless you are CONTINUOUSLY (i.e., every microsecond) ADDING VALUE TO THE USER.

Comment: Hm... I'm a newbie in adnroid development...but... tell me please how mail service works... I suppose it works all the time. Because when the network connection is on, it checks mail.

Comment: @Nick: I can't speak specifically about "how mail service works". It may be watching for broadcasts from `ConnectivityManager` for the state of the data connection, then using that to trigger the initial sync and use `AlarmManager` for follow-up sync work. It definitely dos not run all the time.

Comment: Have a look at application management->working services. I found yandex mail service there. Yandex is russian search system. I have mail account there.

Comment: @Nick: That means the developers of the "yandex mail service" are not following recommended procedures.

Comment: Ok. You convinced me! Trying to redesign application now) and reading the reference))) I'm interested....what for remote services are used...